# "Invalid XPath expression" error in XSL

Tags: xml

```
Unexpected token -
 "string($GPSCgPoint/@oID)'"
select="concat( '2D QA=',format-
number($GPSPointH/h:PointQuality/@CQPos,$dec3),'  1S QA=',format-
number($GPSPointH/h:PointQuality/@CQHeight,$dec3),' 
Time='string($GPSCgPoint/@oID)'  ')"
```

---How to resolve this error---

Comment: What have you tried, and why do you think your attempt(s) have failed? What steps did you perform to encounter this error? What source produced the error? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you format it a bit more carefully:

```
select="concat( '2D QA=',
   format-number($GPSPointH/h:PointQuality/@CQPos,$dec3),
   '  1S QA=',
   format-number($GPSPointH/h:PointQuality/@CQHeight,$dec3),
   'Time='
   string($GPSCgPoint/@oID)
   '  ')"
```

then it's easy to see that there are commas missing after the 5th and 6th arguments to the concat() call.